# How to get access to xml2js result properties

Tags: json, node.js, xml, xml2js

Hi i have parsed the Xml to JSON using xml2js package in node js. The result is like as follows..

[image]

Now i need to get the properties of JSON object, like

```
result.env:Envelope
```

but it generates compile time error. How can i access the object. Any help ??

Answer (score 2):

you can access it by `result['env:Envelope']`.

Suppose you have xml with namespace as follows:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetItems xmlns="http://www.test.com">
         <Items>
            <Object d3p1:type="Fruits" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <Key>11032896</Key>
               <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Object>
            <Object d3p1:type="Fruits" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <Key>11662896</Key>
               <Name>Banana</Name>
            </Object>
        </Items>
    </GetItems>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

You can access it with out getting compile error in TypeScript as

```
result['Envelope']['Body']['GetItems']['Items']['Object']
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is very very skimpy. You should add a sentence or two explaining how this does what it does, and maybe a link to appropriate documentation.